# I have 2 tables.T1-master table,T2-historic data.Want EXISTS query for Name column for all the records in T1 which have multiple Name entries in T2

Tags: mysql, sql, exists

I have 2 tables.

- T1-master table
- T2-historic data

I want EXISTS query for Name column for all the records in T1 which have multiple Name entries in T2.

```
select first_name
     , * 
  from T1
 where exists (select First_name from T1 where T1.First_name != T2.First.name)
```

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and a coherent explanation of what you want.

Comment: Did you mean for the subquery to be `from T2`?

Comment: `T2.First.name` should be `T2.First_name`.

Comment: What is the foreign key that relates the two tables?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this :

```
select t1.* from T1
where exists (select 1 
                from T2
               where T1.First_name = T2.First_name
               having count(*)>1
             )
```

Comment: There's no need to use `GROUP BY` since you're only selecting rows with the same first name.

Answer (score 0):

You can join the master table with a subquery that selects all the duplicate names in `T2`

```
SELECT T1.*
FROM T1
JOIN (
    SELECT first_name
    FROM T2
    GROUP BY first_name
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) AS x ON x.first_name = T1.first_name
```

Answer (score 0):

A correlated subquery seems like the most straightforward approach here. It might also turn out to be more efficient, since no aggregation comes into play:

```
SELECT T1.*
FROM T1
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM T2 WHERE T1.first_name = T2.T1.first_name) > 1
```